# How can I send a transaction with vector of tuple from frontend (react)?

Tags: substrate-front-end

How can I send a transaction with a vector of tuples like Option<Vec<(T::AccountId, u8)>> from frontend (react)? What about None and other types js don't have? Is there any site I can look for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 questions here -

- `None` as found in an `Option`
- `Tuple` types

In the JS world you can do the following -

```js
// signature of this extrinsic is value: Option<(T::AccountId, u8)>
// send None through - mapped from null
await api.tx.someWhere.something(null)

// send a Tuple value through
await api.tx.someWhere.something(['1Test...', 5])
```

So `Tuple` values appear is a JS array with the correct number of elements.

To expand this into your signature type posted above, i.e. an `Option` of a `Vec` of `Tuples` -

```js
// signature of this extrinsic is value: Option<Vec<(T::AccountId, u8)>>
// send None through - mapped from null
await api.tx.someWhere.something(null)

// send a Vec<Tuple> value through (2 values)
await api.tx.someWhere.something([['1Test...', 5], ['1Test...', 6]])
```

The same would apply to eg. `.query.*` if you need to specify a `Tuple`.